# How do i multiply a variable by a variable?

Tags: python-3.x

```
weight = print(int(input('weight: ')))
height = print (float(input('height: ')))

BMI = weight * height
print(BMI)

#i get this back
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Nicholas/Desktop/csp 17/Assign 3-2.py", line 4, in <module>
    BMI = weight * height
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

Comment: What is the result of `print(..)` (which is assigned to the variables)? Why does / might this `<the result of print> * <the result of print>` generate this error? (The error message says exactly why..)

Comment: For BMI, you need another "* height"

Answer (score 3):

`print` does just that: it prints things to your screen. Because it is a function that doesn't return anything else, it will implicitely return `None`.

You can verify this with a list comprehension if you want:

```
>>> x = [print(i) for i in range(5)]
0
1
2
3
4
>>> x
[None, None, None, None, None]
```

Notice that everything is printed, but the resulting variable is a list full of `None`s.

For your code, try without the `print`, because what you're trying to do is not print those things, but assign the variables `weight` and `height` to the inputed value:

```
weight = int(input('weight: '))
height = float(input('height: '))

BMI = weight * height
print(BMI)
```